Suspense thriller about a man who discovers that the company he works for is implanting false memories
It's a corporate suspense thriller. It opens with a man in an interview for his dream job. I think I recall the interviewer asking if he had done anything bad. He lies because he doesn't remember that he had done something bad in his past. The company knows that he lied because they can read his thoughts and memories. He doesn't know this, however. Not yet, anyway. He ends up getting the job and meets a woman that's a high level executive who happens to be the owner/his boss's daughter. The two discover that the corporation is secretly developing technology that will implant false memories in people's minds. The boss finds out and the two go on the run together.
I want to say the lead guy is a young actor, like a Joseph Gordon Levitt type. It's no more than 5 years old and it's a pretty obscure film. Either that or it was never released publicly. I really can't remember. 

There was a Stargate SG-1 episode with a similar plot

Could be Cypher

Hoping for a more exciting life than the suburban drawl he currently inhabits, nerdy salary man Morgan Sullivan takes a job as an industrial spy at Digicorp, a global computer corporation. Digicorp assigns him the duty of flying to various conventions around America, recording the speeches that are made. But when Sullivan meets a mysterious woman he begins to realize that his job may not be what it seems, as he descends into a dark underworld of brainwashing and struggles to maintain his own identity.





Could it be "Branded"?

"The film starts with documentary-style flashbacks showing Misha's rise to a powerful marketing executive. Now in Moscow 2017, Misha is a powerful marketing executive working to spread Western brands, and like the businesses he works for nothing will stop him in his greed, until the imprisonment and death of an overweight girl undergoing extensive plastic surgery to become skinny. Following a vision in which Misha sacrifices a heifer to God, he begins to receive strange visions depicting the brands control over people. He returns to work and guided by these visions, Misha attempts to stop the growth of the brands in post-Communist Russia by encouraging the brand to attack each other in their advertising campaigns. There is some debate whether Misha believes that the worship of global brands is Idolatry and his visions depicting the brands are controlling people causing them to sin, or whether his belief is that monopoly is evil and his intention is to create a Western style free-market economy."

It sounds like it has more to do with brainwashing than false memories but it is also quite obscure. 




Hmmm... No that's not it. Although this looks interesting. Thanks~!
